# translate/mask real sip address and simplified sip address

Tags: sip

The original sip address is `sip:a5bcdefXyZ@sip.externalservice.com` (this is an external service provider). I would like to use my simplified own name e.g. `sip:myname@sip.mydomain.com` and when this address is used, it should be finally translated to `sip:a5bcdefXyZ@sip.externalservice.com` on the background.

For me and as well for my colleagues it is much easier to remember just 
`sip:myname@sip.mydomain.com`, 
`sip:hisname@sip.mydomain.com`, 
`sip:hername@sip.mydomain.com`. So the main goal is to use our own addresses, and these addresses should be "translated" on the background (via our own server) to the final sip address.

Does any idea please how to set up this translation of addresses? (I have Debian server)

Comment: An easier approach would be to use a softphone that lets you create contacts and do the mapping in the address book, e.g. "Joe Bloggs" -> sip:a5bcdefXyZ@sip.externalservice.com. If you really do have to do the SIPURI mapping tehn you'll need to set up your own SIP Proxy such as Kamailio.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using standard SIP URI refinement, set-up a registrar domain **sip.my-domain.com** and do a registration of `sip:myname@sip.mydomain.com` with binding `sip:a5bcdefXyZ@sip.externalservice.com`.

It should be stressed that you are responsible of register/unregister the external SIP line in accordance (keep in sync) of the the external provider remote registration.

However, remember that it implies a 1-to-1 relation so do no do that on a public SIP trunk.